# add color from array list to li then loop back

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, colors, html-lists

i have a list of colors that i want to add to a each li in my ul, but after the number of li's passes the number of colors i would like the colors to start from the first color. Here's what i mean

http://jsfiddle.net/NjqYA/57/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var color=['#0098c3','#bed600','#a30050','#9b1889'];
$('#div_id ul li').each(function(i){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor',color[i]);
});});
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: add `i = i % color.length;` before the css background-color

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulus operator to loop around.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var color=['#0098c3','#bed600','#a30050','#9b1889'];
    $('#div_id ul li').each(function(i){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor',color[i % color.length]);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/NjqYA/59/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use modulus to do this.

Initialize a counter `c`, use `c++ % color.length` as a index so everytime it gets above the length of `color` it jumps back to `0`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = ['#0098c3', '#bed600', '#a30050', '#9b1889'];
  var c = 0;
  $('#div_id ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', color[c++ % color.length]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_id">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 8</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected version, using modulus to get the remainder:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var color=['#0098c3','#bed600','#a30050','#9b1889'];
  $('#div_id ul li').each(function(i){
      var colorIndex = i % color.length;
      $(this).css('backgroundColor',color[colorIndex]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you making the var colorIndex? You can just put color.length in the array call.

Comment: Ha ha, my version is almost the same as Barmar, but I have not seen his before. It must be years of practice. My comments are better but his DEMO bits it all. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Well just try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var color=['#0098c3','#bed600','#a30050','#9b1889'];
$('#div_id ul li').each(function(i){
        i=i % color.length;
        $(this).css('backgroundColor',color[i]);
});
});
```

If `i` reaches `color.length` then initialise it; here's [**the working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NjqYA/63/).

Comment: variable i is dduplicated

Comment: Great - lets arrow up

Answer (score 0):

Just add `i = i % color.length` before the css background-color

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = ['#0098c3', '#bed600', '#a30050', '#9b1889'];
  $('#div_id ul li').each(function(i) {
    i = i % color.length
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', color[i]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_id">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stupid link 8</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```